# Re-evaluating a function to get a new random value in python

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.x

here is the code that I am having a problem with(simplified to make it clearer). It is for a text based game just to help learn things.

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 5
        self.moveset = [None,None,None,None] 

    def movesetleveling(self): 
        if self.level > 4:
            self.moveset[0] = Punch(self.level)

def punch(level):
    damagedealt = random.randint(0,5)**level
    return damagedealt
```

I would like to know how I can make `self.moveset[0] = Punch()` rather than being equal to the output of `Punch()` in this block of code. So that everytime i run it in a while loop it will re-evaluate the output of Punch() rather than evaluating `Punch()` once and assigning that to the 0th index of `self.moveset[0]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "run it in a while loop"?  How are you intending to use `moveset`?

Comment: Do you want to have four random punch levels in `self.moveset` or do you want the first item in `self.moveset` to be a random punch value in each iteration of your loop?

Comment: @BrenBarn `moveset` will be used to show a selection of player moves. they will select a move from the list which will then be evaluated to produce an integer value which will be a damagestat. this damagestat will affect a Foes health. I have created a while loop which does this over and over but each time it uses the same value for `self.moveset[0]` rather than getting a new value.

Comment: Add your while loop to the question

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i want the first item to be a random punch value in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid To put the while loop in i would have to copy a very large amount of code for it to make sense. I am almost certain that the while loop is not the problem though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign a function to `self.moveset[0]` instead of its result (using [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools#functools.partial)):

```
from functools import partial

self.moveset[0] = partial(punch, self.level)
```

Then later, in your `while` loop, just call it:

```
while True:
    new_punch_every_time = self.moveset[0]() #note: parentheses
```

`self.moveset[0]()` calls `punch` function with `level` parameter set to `self.level` (its value at the time of `partial` call).

It works because functions, methods are first class citizens in Python. You can pass them as parameters to other functions, return from functions, bind to a different name, append to a list, etc.

Comment: `partial`? to a beginner? ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye: OP explicitly said: *"to help learn things"*. `functools.partial()` is the thing to learn. It is not a crocodile; it won't eat you if you come near it.

Comment: Nice, but I suspect the problem might be in the while loop (of the original question)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian just had a look at the `functools` docs and i somewhat agree with @thefourtheye 's sentiment. my head is swimming. A slightly more beginner friendly answer would be greatly appreciated if you know of one!

Comment: @user3124704: which concept/word do you not understand in this sentence: *"`self.moveset[0]()` calls `punch` function with `level` parameter set to `self.level` (its value at the time of the `partial` call)."*? Do you know what function is? What is function parameter? What does it mean to call a function with a given parameter?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i understand the ins and outs of functions. i understand that you mean that the `punch(level)` (level is the parameter) function is called as `punch(self.level)`. i do not understand the "it's value at the time of the partial call" part.

Comment: @user3124704: if you use `self.level = some_value` some time *after* the call (`self.moveset[0] = partial(punch, self.level)`) then it won't affect it. It is the difference between `lambda level=self.level: punch(level)` and `lambda: punch(self.level)`. The latter will use the latest `self.level` value unlike the former and the function created using `partial`.